CL Macro does not resolve properly
In Common Lisp I have defind this macro:
(defmacro gen-update-func (func-name table id keyparam)
  `(defun ,func-name (db ,id)
     (let ((data))
       (keyparams ,keyparam)

       (clsql:update-records ',table
                 :database db
                 :where [= ',id id]
                 :av-pairs data))))

I call it with:
(gen-update-func add-sp spender spenderid (vorname name))

macroexpand-1 returns this:
(defun add-sp (db spenderid)
  (let ((data))
    ;(keyparams (vorname name))
    (clsql-sys:update-records 'spender :database db :where [= 'spenderid id]
                              :av-pairs data)))

This is expected.
When I call it, it resolves the line ":where [= ',id id]" to:
:WHERE SPENDENDB::[= 'SPENDENDB::SPENDERID SPENDENDB::ID]

This is wrong. I want to insert [= literally without leading SPENDENDB::. This is intended:
:WHERE [= 'SPENDENDB::SPENDERID SPENDENDB::ID]

How can I achieve that?
The syntax [= ... ] is a special SQL syntax from clsql.

In the file where you define your macro, you are using the [= ...] syntax but you are probably not in the appropriate readtable to do so. This is why [= is parsed as a symbol, which is why it is printed with the package prefix later.
According to the CLSQL documentation - locally enable sql reader syntax, you should be able to enable the syntax when defining the macro:
#.(locally-enable-sql-reader-syntax)
    
(defmacro ...)
    
#.(restore-sql-reader-syntax-state)
  

Alternatively, you enable it inside a file:
(in-package :my-package)
(clsql:file-enable-sql-reader-syntax)

When trying to use this syntax, I wrote:
* '[= 'a b]
(CLSQL-SYS:SQL-= 'A B)

As a consequence, you could directly use the equality operator (clsql-sys:sql-= ...) without relying on the helper syntax. Looking at the documentation it is a bit more portable apparently to do it as follows:
`(clsql-sys:sql-operation '= ,a ,b)


Thank you for referring me to the SQL package documentation from Lispworks. There I found the solution that is little different. I had to replace the sql special form in the :where line by function calls to sql-operation and sql-expression.
 :where (clsql:sql-operation '=     (clsql:sql-expression :attribute ',id)     ,id)
